# Can't select 2 tables at the same time

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a `pesId` (peopleId) column at pessoas (people) where is stored data from medics and patient. Also I have a table that stores medical consult information like Date, patient id, medic id and diagnostic.

I got to select the `conDate`, `Patient Name` (from table 'ppl'), `Medic Name` (also from 'ppl') and `Diagnostic` but I am having trouble for hours doing this. I am very noob at MySQL but I am trying to learn. May anyone help me with this logic problem?

I tried many methods.

```
select conDat, pa.pesId = pacientes.pacId, me.pesId = medicos.medId, conDiag, case when null then 'Indefinido' end
    from consultas
    inner join pessoas as pa on pa.pesId = pacientes.pacId
    inner join pessoas as me on me.pesId = medicos.medId;
```

Thank you very much

This is my creating tables code:

```
create table consultas (

conId int primary key auto_increment,
conDat date not null,
pacId int not null,
medId int not null,
conDiag varchar (30) );

create table pessoas (

pesId int primary key auto_increment,
pesNome varchar (50) not null);

create table pacientes (

pacId int primary key default 1,
pacTel varchar (20) not null,
pacAtiv bool);

create table medicos (

medId int primary key default 1,
medCPF varchar (20) not null,
medAtiv bool);
```

Comment: You need to use alias in select...`like "select ppl.column1, ppl,column2, table2.column1....`

Comment: If you show us the create table, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Your case statement also needs to be an evalutation. When "what" IS NULL then 'Indefinido' end.

Comment: Hi Vasque, please remove the solution from the question. You might add an own answer if you like and it differs from given solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't got it. Is there any problem in placing a solution at the end of the question? I just wrote the 2 ways it worked for me. ( I am being seriously, it's my first question here and don't know how things works here ). Thank you :)

Comment: I just got it bummi, if I place a Solution after the question ppl tends not to Upvote the answers. I am sorry, already removed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your tables, you may be trying for the following:

```
select 
    c.conDat
    , pa.pesId
    , me.pesId
    , conDiag
    , case when 'yourColumnValue' is null then 'Indefinido' 
      else 'yourColumnValue'
    end as 
from consultas c
inner join pessoas as pa 
    on pa.pesId = c.pacId
inner join medicos as me 
    on pa.pesId = me.medId;
```

Note: your case statement will need a value filled in.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your specifications well, and although I haven't tested this query in the server yet, it should work:

```
SELECT CO.conDat, 
       PA.pesNome                         AS paciente, 
       ME.pesNome                         AS medico,
       COALESCE(CO.conDiag, 'indefinido') AS condiag
    FROM  consultas    CO
    INNER JOIN pessoas PA 
    ON    PA.pesId   = CO.pacId
    INNER JOIN pessoas ME
    ON    ME.pesId   = CO.medId;
```

Since this query JOINS the table `consultas` with `pessoas` twice in order to retrieve the `pessoas.pesNome` column values related to `medicos` and `pacientes` respectively, it is important that you look with special attention to the aliases given to the `PA.pesNome` and `ME.pesNome` columns (by way of the `AS` keyword in the SELECT statement), because such aliases are used for the purpose of displaying different column headers in the obtained result set, and thus, ambiguities are avoided, since the meaning of each column, `paciente` or `medico`, is clear.

For handling the cases when `consultas.conDiag` contains `NULL`, the above query takes advantage of the [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which, in this particular case, substitutes `NULL` values in said column with your custom defined string ‘indefinido’.

Alternately, you can try this other query, which shows a different method for replacing the `consultas.conDiag` column value when it holds `NULL`, via the [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT CO.conDat, 
       PA.pesNome                       AS paciente, 
       ME.pesNome                       AS medico,
       IFNULL(CO.conDiag, 'indefinido') AS conDiag 
    FROM  consultas    CO
    INNER JOIN pessoas PA 
    ON    PA.pesId   = CO.pacId
    INNER JOIN pessoas ME
    ON    ME.pesId   = CO.medId;
```